# Not all data is displaying

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to echo the data from the following table titled sectionamain, however I am only getting the data from the first row (TitleID = 1)

```
|TitleID | MainTitle            | 
|1       |This is a title       | 
|2       |This is another title |
```

The below is the PHP code i am using:

```
function get_practices_titles() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM sectionamain ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY TitleID ASC";
    $A_list = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($A_list);
    return $A_list;    
}

function practices_titles() {
   $output = "<div class=\"container inner\">\n";
   $output .= "<div class=\"wrap\">\n";
   $A_set = get_practices_titles();
   while ($list_A = mysqli_fetch_assoc($A_set)) {
       $output .= "<h1 class\=showcontent\" id=";
       $output .= htmlentities($list_A["TitleID"]);
       $output .= ">";
       $output .= htmlentities($list_A["MainTitle"]);
       $output .= "</h1>";
       mysqli_free_result($A_set);
       $output .="</div>\n</div>";
       return $output;
    };
}
```

I thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: what is confirm_query() function?

Comment: I believe you need to move `mysqli_free_result($A_set);` to outside of your while loop. You are getting rid of your results before you are done looping through them maybe? Move it to after your while loop is finished. From the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php `You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), when your result object is not needed anymore.` But you still need it - you are freeing the memory after looping through only one result.

Comment: @dgig is right; you are emptying the array after the first loop. Try to comment out that row and you should see the full set of results

Comment: This is the confirm_query function     <br>function confirm_query($result_set) {
  if (!$result_set) {
    die("Database query failed.");
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to move `mysqli_free_result($A_set);` to outside of your while loop.

You are getting rid of your results before you are done looping through them. Move it to after your while loop is finished.

From the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

> You should always free your result with mysqli_free_result(), when
>   your result object is not needed anymore.

But you still need it - you are freeing the memory after looping through only one result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following 3 lines from the loop to the end of the function :

```
  mysqli_free_result($A_set);
   $output .="</div>\n</div>";
   return $output;
```

so your function will be something like this:

```
  function practices_titles() {
 $output = "<div class=\"container inner\">\n";
 $output .= "<div class=\"wrap\">\n";
 $A_set = get_practices_titles();
  while ($list_A = mysqli_fetch_assoc($A_set)) {
   $output .= "<h1 class\=showcontent\" id=";
   $output .= htmlentities($list_A["TitleID"]);
   $output .= ">";
   $output .= htmlentities($list_A["MainTitle"]);
   $output .= "</h1>";

};
   mysqli_free_result($A_set);
   $output .="</div>\n</div>";
   return $output;
  }
```